# Does Web3j require port forwarding to use?

Tags: java, ethereum, web3-java

I am trying to use web3j in java, but when i try to make a web3j object it gives an error

```
         Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService());
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TreeNode
```

i think it's because port forwarding is not enabled, am i right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are encountering is not related to port, but to a missing dependency:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TreeNode

This means that you are lacking the class [com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TreeNode](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TreeNode.html?is-external=true) in your class path or module path.

I don't know web3j but their site seems to references Maven or Gradle. You should try with those build tool since they will provide you the dependencies.

Comment: i was facing issues downloading using gradle and maven so i downloaded everything manually all 11 libraries, would that still result in missing libraries ?

Comment: I can't tell for missing libraries: I use maven because that's what a dependency manager is for :)